# Trying and failing to render two tables side by side with HTML and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, .net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to render some simple HTML/Bootstrap tables side by side but getting stuck at this even after trying the previous solutions offered from on here. I'm sure it's something simple but I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

I have two lists in my model, of equal size, that I would like to display beside each other. The correct data is being displayed, but I simply cannot get them to render alongside each other:

//Layout

```
@using RazorLight

<html>
<head>
    <title>Daily Email</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//DailyReportingEmail

```
@using Solution.Shared.Models
@inherits RazorLight.TemplatePage<Report>
@model Report
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <div>

    <p>
        <strong>
            This is an automated email.
            Do not reply to this email.
        </strong>
    </p>

    <p class="lead">
        The Data is sourced from Report.
    </p>

    <h1>Daily Totals: </h1>

    @{
        await IncludeAsync("Includes/DailyTotalsTable.cshtml", Model);
    }

</div>
```

//DailyTotalsTable

```
@using Solution.Shared.Models
@inherits RazorLight.TemplatePage<Report>
@model Report

<div class="col-6">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Previous</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var record in Model.PreviousTotals)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@record.Category</td>
                <td>@record.Value</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Current</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var record in Model.CurrentTotals)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@record.Value</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added bootstrap class **row**. Wrap your code around div with class="row"

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Previous</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var record in Model.PreviousTotals)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@record.Category</td>
                <td>@record.Value</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Current</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var record in Model.CurrentTotals)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@record.Value</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Perfect, thanks.